# Where are the username and password stored in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, logins

I'm using the PostgreSQL database. In it I create users. So I want to know

1. Where are the User name and Password stored?
2. Whether the Password is stored as plain text or encrypted data?
3. Whether root user is able to read the password or not?

Answer (score 16):

1. In [pg_authid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-authid.html)
2. By default encrypted, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html)
3. no, not possible (if encrypted)

In comments, you asked:

> So may I know how you said not possible (if encrypted). If not encrypted also unable to view right

If it's not encrypted, it's stored in plain text and then the superuser *can* read the password (but who with a sane mind would store a password unencrypted). You can easily test that for yourself using `create user foo unencrypted password 'bar';`

Comment: Encrypted or hashed?

Comment: @NickT Cryptographically hashed.

Comment: The [documentation for PostgreSQL 14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) suggests that the password is always stored hashed, and that the `UNENCRYPTED` keyword in the `CREATE ROLE` is ignored.